# Prevent opening ionic keyboard on button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I made an Ionic v6 (using Capacitor) and Angular 14 app that has an input field and + and - button next to it for increasing and decreasing the number in that input field...

The issue I am facing is the keyboard... When I click/tap on the input field the keyboard opens up and a page scroll happens to scroll to the input. That is good and correct. But the issue is with the + and - buttons... When clicking/taping on the button it also opens the keyboard but the scroll to that input doesn't happen.

So my question is... how do I prevent the keyboard from opening on these two buttons or if there is perhaps a way to scroll to that input?

Here is the HTML code how the input is constructed and an image how it looks like:

```
        <ion-item lines="none" slot="end" [disabled]="product.stock === null">
          <ion-icon color="vigros" name="remove-circle" (click)="decrementQty(product)"></ion-icon>
          <ion-input type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" [(ngModel)]="product.qty"></ion-input>
          <ion-icon color="vigros" name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(product)"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
```

And here is the TS code of +/- button function as requested in the coments...

```
  incrementQty(produkt: Product['product']) {
    const increasedQty = this.product.qty += 1.00;

    this.cartService.addUpdateProductToCart(increasedQty, produkt).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.product.qty = this.product.qty;
        this.getCart();
        Keyboard.hide();
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      }
    );
  }

  decrementQty(produkt: Product['product']) {
    if(this.product.qty > 0) {
      const decreasedQty = this.product.qty -1;

      this.cartService.addUpdateProductToCart(decreasedQty, produkt).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.product.qty -= 1;
          this.getCart();
          Keyboard.hide();
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error', error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

[image]

here is also the image of constructed DOM as requested in the comments:
[image]

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @E.Maggini don't you se the HTML markup of the input field with the buttons?

Comment: I am referring to TS file, not HTML. There are references to decrementQty and incrementQty. You could also post the inspect of the elements to show what the actual rendered DOM looks like.

Comment: @E.Maggini I have added the TS code and an Image of constructed DOM

Answer (score 0):

can u try this example of code

```
<ion-item lines="none" slot="end" [disabled]="product.stock === null">
<ion-icon color="vigros" name="remove-circle" 
(click)="decrementQty(product); inputQty.blur()"></ion-icon>
<ion-input #inputQty type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" 
[(ngModel)]="product.qty"></ion-input>
<ion-icon color="vigros" name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(product); 
inputQty.blur()"></ion-icon>
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: Sorry but nothing is different. Except I'm getting a warning: Unresolved function or method blur()

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the elements are on top of each other maybe add some padding to the buttons on the sides to give it some space to make the target area bigger.

Since your just using ion-icon tags, you need to add padding or margins to each icon tag, or wrap each icon in the ion-button tag.